# mysql keeps giving sql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
//database class    
class dbmgmt{
            public $tbl_name;
            public $field_arr;
            public $val_arr;
            public $cond_arr;

            function execute($sql){
                global $conn;
                $result=$conn->query($sql);
                if(!$result) echo "Error: ".$conn->error;
            }
            function insert(){
                $sql="INSERT INTO ".$this->tbl_name." SET ";

                for($i=0;$i++;$i<count($this->field_arr)){
                    if($i!=(count($this->field_arr)-1)){
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr.",";
                    }else{
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr;                   
                    }
                }

                $this->execute($sql);   
            }
    }

    $ado=new dbmgmt();

//admin_add.php
$ado->tbl_name="tbl_admin";
$ado->field_arr=array("username","password",'type','email');
$ado->val_arr=array($username,create_hash($password),$admin_type,$email);
                $ado->insert();
                if($conn->connect_error){
                    die("Failed to add Record: ".$conn->connect_errno. ' '.$conn->connect_error);
                }else{

                    echo "Succesfully Added Record";
                    echo "<script>window.location=".ADMIN_PAGE."</script>";
                }
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How does the query look like right before you execute it?

Comment: You are writing `INSERT` query with `SET`? Is it corretc

Comment: `SET` can be used for `INSERT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: echoing gave me just this "INSERT INTO tbl_admin SET"

Comment: @JayBlanchard will get rid of our comments now. They're no longer needed. But, a cappucino is always needed. *Cheers*

Comment: @hengecyche Try updating your question with the full query being executed. If `INSERT INTO tbl_admin SET` *is* your full query, the error should be quite obvious.

Comment: I'll likely drink coffee this afternoon just to keep me hydrated @Fred-ii-

Comment: thanks guys the loop was my bad forgot the positioning and used quotes to escape " and the code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is you need to quote string value:

```
$sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=\"".$this->val_arr."\"";
```

And value need to be escaped using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

One issue is in your for loop:

```
for($i=0;$i++;$i<count($this->field_arr)){
                    if($i!=(count($this->field_arr)-1)){
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr.",";
                    }else{
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr;                   
                    }
```

Should be with the counter after the ending criteria

```
for($i=0;$i<count($this->field_arr;$i++)){
                    if($i!=(count($this->field_arr)-1)){
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr.",";
                    }else{
                        $sql.=$this->field_arr[i]."=".$this->val_arr;                   
                    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing he probably needs to enclose his values in quotes as well, but my php is VERY rusty.